# ImportError: Unable to find an implementation of PyGUI for this installation

Tags: python, pygui

I had a simple app up and running that used the PyGui package. After I decided I had everything working I refactored my code and basically broke it up over multiple files, but I am fairly sure I did not change the location of any files. Now when I try to run my app It gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "blobedit.py", line 16, in <module>
    from GUI import Application, ScrollableView, Document, Window, Cursor, rgb
  File "/Users/<myusername>/Desktop/BlobEdit/GUI/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Unable to find an implementation of PyGUI for this installation")
ImportError: Unable to find an implementation of PyGUI for this installation
```

I have tried moving files around for weeks and can't find the problem. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have a directory `GUI` and inside it `__init__.py`, this makes the directory an importable package.

Unfortunately, PyGUI *also* provides a GUI package. Due to the way Python searches for packages to import, your `GUI` has come up first and this is what is causing problems.

The simple way to solve it is to rename your GUI directory `/Users/Destkop/BlobEdit/GUI` to something else.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried that but it didn't seem to work. There is a good chance I did it wrong though. When I get a chance I am going to try simply installing the package with pip and see how that goes.